# GIT: How to checkout file to head, even if the file was removed?

Tags: git, copy, reset, git-checkout, revision

I want to create script, which would:

1. restore file to revision when my changes was (I know the revision
   and changed files from git log --name-status),
2. copy file,
3. restore the file to HEAD.

So I do:

```
git checkout (hash with my changes) file.x
cp file.x directory/to/copy/file.x
git checkout HEAD file.x
```

and it works for vast majority of situations, but not all of them -it doesn't work when the file was renamed or deleted in newer revision and doesn't exist in HEAD.

So my question is: **how to restore single file from old revision to HEAD, even if the file doesn't exist in HEAD?**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the commit you want is testcommit:

```
git checkout testcommit file/to/restore
```

The [git checkout](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-checkout.html) man page gives more information.

As a side note, I've always been uncomfortable with this command because it's used for both ordinary things (changing between branches) and unusual destructive things (discarding changes in the working directory).

Comment: Unfortunately the command produces error message, when file was renamed in some revision.

Comment: error: pathspec 'file/to/restore' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: `git checkout 08618129e66127921fbfcbc205a06153c92622fe -- [full/path]` to be more clear `git checkout mybranchname ~/src/myapp/myfile.txt`